# ANTLR Token auto-generated in lexer

Tags: antlr, lexer, auto-generate

I have to write a parser to parse input into a parse-tree but i ran to a problem with my tokens and tokens auto-generated. The following example is a short versions of my problem .This is the grammar:

```
    s : a B a;
    a : '-' C | C;
    B : '-' | '+';
    C : '1' | '2';>
    WS : ( ' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n')+ -> skip ;
```

My input: `- 1 - 2`.

My output tree is `(s (a - 1) <missing B> (a - 2))` .

The output tree i want is `(s (a - 1) - (a  2))`

There is some tokens like T__* which is auto generated in file lexer.java. I believe one of them would be `T__* : '-'` which duplicate my token B. Because it appear first, no symbol `-` lead to B. All of symbols `-`  would lead to T__*. I think this is the reason. Am i right?

What should i do to get a correct tree?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, i got the solution. New grammar should be like this.

```
    s : a b a;
    a : '-' c | c;
    b : ADD | SUB;
    c : ONE | TWO;
    ADD : '+';
    SUB : '-';
    ONE : '1';
    TWO : '2';
    WS : ( ' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n')+ -> skip ;
```

Although i find down the solution, i still don't know what happened with my wrong grammar. Anyway, hope this help someone has the same problem.